# Exercise 5, Section 13 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> Show that if $\mathscr{A}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$, then the topology generated by $\mathscr{A}$ equals the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that contain $\mathscr{A}$. Prove the same if $\mathscr{A}$ is a subbasis.

I would first rephrase the problem:

> If $\mathscr{A}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$, then $\mathscr{I}_\mathscr{A}=\cap_{\alpha \in A} \mathscr{T}_{\alpha}$, where each  $\mathscr{T}_{\alpha}$ is topology on $X$, $\mathscr{A} \subseteq \mathscr{T}_{\alpha}$

**My attempt:** let $\mathscr{I}_\mathscr{A}$ denotes topology generated by basis $\mathscr{A}$. To show $\cap_ {\alpha \in A} \mathscr{T}_{\alpha} \subseteq \mathscr{I}_{\mathscr{A}}$.**Proof:** If $U\in \cap_ {\alpha \in A} \mathscr{T}_{\alpha}$, then $U\in \mathscr{T}_{\alpha}, \forall \alpha \in A$. Since $\mathscr{A}$ is basis, $\forall x\in X, \exists \mathcal{A} \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $x \in \mathcal{A}$. So, $\forall x \in U, \exists \mathcal{A}_{x}\in \mathscr{A}$ such that $x\in \mathcal{A}_{x}$. Thus, $U \subseteq \cup_{x \in U} \mathcal{A}_{x}$. If $y \in \cup_{x \in U} \mathcal{A}_{x}$, then $y\in \mathcal{A}_{j}$, for some $j\in U$. Since $\mathcal{A}_{j}\in \mathscr{A}$, $\mathcal{A}_{j} \subseteq X$. So, $y\in \mathcal{A}_{j} \subseteq X$[**Edit:** next step/claim is complete garbage]. Thus, $\cup_{x \in U} \mathcal{A}_{x} \subseteq U$. Hence $U = \cup_{x \in U} \mathcal{A}_{x}$. By lemma 13.1, $U\in \mathscr{T}_{\mathscr{A}}$. **Is this proof correct?**

The way I proved this inclusion, I don’t think it’s correct, because it shows any subset of $X$ can be written as unions of elements of $\mathscr{A}$. Maybe somewhere in the proof I did something wrong.

The ideal solution to this problem is here: [Prob. 5, Sec. 13 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to distinguish between a basis and a subbasis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2203489/861687)

Comment: I didn’t show reverse inclusion because it’s proof is relatively easy and straightforward.

Comment: I am sorry but the fonts are really illegible to me lol

Comment: @Hermis14 Is there any way I can fix it? I used different ways of writing $A$ because it’s looks coherent.

Comment: It's just due to my personal preference; I am not familiar with such fonts. They are probably problematic only to me. You can replace curly fonts with more plain ones to save me :) But I am not sure I can answer this question after all...

Comment: @Hermis14 Those symbols are used in Munkres Topology book. That’s why I’m using it. You can imagine different symbols in your mind while looking at those symbols which is bothering you.

Comment: Why do you put all the effort in the trivial part of the proof? It's clear you don't really understand the statement.

Comment: People need the truth, that's what maths is about after all; even if you don't like the truth: deal with it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I’m not at all surprise that proof is wrong. Before posting, I knew that proof was wrong. But at that time I couldn’t see why it was wrong. I spotted a “stupid” step after posting this post.

Comment: By definition of generation, we get the smallest topology containing A. This smallest topology must be the intersection.

Comment: I think the statement of the problem makes it much harder then it should be. I wonder what the words *basis* and *sub-basis* are doing in the statement, besides making it unnecessarily complicated. You have a family of subsets $\mathcal{C}$. The intersection of all topologies that contain $\mathcal{C}$ is the smallest topology (which then, exists, by the way) that contains $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want

$$\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}} = \bigcap\{\mathcal{T}\mid \mathcal{T} \text{ a topology on } X \text{ and } \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{T}\}\tag{1}$$

As by definition $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$ is **a** topology that contains $\mathcal{A}$ we have immediately that the right hand intersection is a subset of $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$ in both the base and the subbase case. So $\supseteq$ is trivial (any intersection is a subset of all its constituent sets).

The other inclusion follows from *how* we construct $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is a base, then any $O \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$ is by definition a union $O = \bigcup \mathcal{A}'$ for some $\mathcal{A}' \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. If $\mathcal{T}$ is *any* topology containing $\mathcal{A}$ it *must* contain $O$ by the union axiom. So $O \in \mathcal{T}$ and as $\mathcal{T}$ was arbitrary, $O$ is in the right hand intersection. Hence $\subseteq$ for the base case.

The subbase case is similar: we first construct the base $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{A}}$ from the subbase (the finite intersections) and any topology $\mathcal{T}$ containing $\mathcal{A}$ contains this base by the intersection axiom. Then we apply the union axiom again to conclude that any $O \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$ also is in such a $\mathcal{T}$ etc. So $\subseteq $ holds once more.

Looking at it from a higher standpoint: the intersection in $(1)$ is by **definition** the topology generated by a subfamily $\mathcal{A}$; it's always well-defined because the set of topologies always includes the discrete topology (the power set) and any intersection of topologies on a set is a topology on that set (topologies form a complete lattice). The point of the Munkres exercise is to show that the *internal* way to generate a topology from a base or a subbase actually coincides with the aforementioned abstract view in both cases.

Comment: I obviously known this approach to the solution. I’m looking for some different way to solve this problem. It’s very natural way to start with $U\in \cap_ {\alpha \in A} \mathscr{T}_{\alpha}$, so is it possible to proof this problem using $U\in \cap_ {\alpha \in A} \mathscr{T}_{\alpha}$ approach.

Comment: @user264745 There *is* no other approach in Munkres' framework; this is the unique solution to the problem, in essence. Anything else is a waste of time. Believe me.